# Implementing variational autoencoder in keras with reconstruction probability

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement the variational autoencoder in keras and use reconstruction probability instead of reconstruction error for anomaly detection. There is an example in deep learning 4j and someone has already asked the same question here: [Variational autoencoder and reconstruction Log Probability vs Reconstruction error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070393/variational-autoencoder-and-reconstruction-log-probability-vs-reconstruction-err)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your use case. In the example below, you can take the trace of the inner product of the reconstruction matrix and the input matrix (provided it makes sense to case the reconstruction matrix as a probability). Then edit your custom loss function to return that value instead (or in addition to) of standard VAE loss. Adam doesn't care what is being optimized, however, the nice benefits of using a VAE if you are not using its loss might vanish.
From [here](https://github.com/samsinai/VAE_protein_function/blob/master/VAE_for_protein_function_prediction.ipynb):

```
def compute_log_probability(one_hot_inp,pwm_output):
    prod_mat=np.matmul(one_hot_inp.T,pwm_output)
    log_prod_mat=np.log(prod_mat)
    sum_diag=np.trace(log_prod_mat)
    return sum_diag

output = x_decoded.reshape(dim1,dim2)
output = normalize(output,axis=0, norm='l1') #column-wise normalization in this case
prob=compute_log_probability(input,output)
```

In the protein input case it makes sense to normalize per column because each column can only really have one value. In other cases you might want